# Google AdminDirectory api in not updating addresses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, user-profile

I am trying to update user's reach profile attributes with below apps script. It is updating all fields except only addresses. Kindly suggest if I am missing anything. Below is the part of code:

```
  var resource = {
    organizations:
    [{title: designation,
      department: department,
     }],
    addresses: [
      {
        locality: "Pune",
        streetAddress:"Kothrud",
        postalCode:"411038",
        primary:true,
        region:"Maharashtra",
        type: "work",
      }
    ],
    phones: [{
      type: "work",
      value: phone,
      },
      {
      type: "mobile",
      value: mobile,
      },
      {
      customType: "Extension",
      value: land_line,
      },
      {
     customType:"Middle Name",
     value: middle,
     }],
  }

  var result = AdminDirectory.Users.update(resource, email_address)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of update you could try `result = AdminDirectory.Users.patch(resource, userId);`

API link for your reference [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/patch).

Hope that helps!